# Is rememberDismissState cached for LazyColumn Key?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, swipe, compose-recomposition

I have composable

```
fun ShowProduct(name: String, image: String, onDismissed: () -> Unit) {
    var state = rememberDismissState();

    if (state.isDismissed(DismissDirection.EndToStart)) {
        onDismissed()
    }

    SwipeToDismiss(
        state = state,
        background = { ShowSwipableActions(name) },
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp, 10.dp)
            .height(75.dp),
        directions = setOf(DismissDirection.EndToStart),
        dismissThresholds = { _ -> FractionalThreshold(0.5f) }
    ) {
        /* Content */
    }
}
```

Which is rendered like this

```
@Composable
fun ProductsScreen(vm: ProductsListViewModel = ProductsListViewModel()){
    ShowList(
        vm.products,
        { x -> vm.removeProduct(x) },
        vm.isLoadingProducts.value,
        {
            vm.refresh()
        }
    )
}
```

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ShowList(
    products: List<Product>,
    onDismissed: (productId: String) -> Unit,
    refreshing: Boolean,
    onRefreshRequested: () -> Unit
) {
    val haptic = LocalHapticFeedback.current

    PullToRefreshCompose(
        refreshing,
        onRefreshRequested = onRefreshRequested,
        onRefreshDistanceReached = {
            haptic.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackType.LongPress)
        }) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            items(items = products, key = { product -> product.id }) { product ->
                ShowProduct(
                    product.name,
                    product.image,
                    onDismissed = { onDismissed.invoke(product.id) });
            }
        }
    }

}
```

ViewModel:

```
class ProductsListViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private var _products = mutableStateListOf<Product>()
    val products: List<Product>
        get() = _products

    var isLoadingProducts = mutableStateOf(false);

    fun removeProduct(id: String) {
        _products.removeIf { x -> x.id == id }
    }

    fun refresh() {
            isLoadingProducts.value = true

            if(_products.any()){
                _products.clear()
            }

            for (i in 0..50) {
                _products.add(
                    Product(
                        i.toString(),
                        "Product $i",
                        "*image url*"
                    )
                );
            }

            isLoadingProducts.value = false
    }
}
```

If I dismiss an item and then call the refresh() function in my ViewModel, the dismissed keys will be displayed already in the dismissed state. Should I use completely unique keys for the entire lifetime of LazyColumn if I delete and add the same item?

For example

```
i.toString() + System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your posted code is incomplete, I just assumed some parts of it, and when I filled the missing parts, I only created `2` items instead of `50` as I can't differentiate every red `Box` that I created with that many items. What I encountered was a crash, based on the GIF showing the actions being done. After swipe-deleting the 2 items and clicking the "Refresh" button, it crashes with the stacktrace below.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.stackoverflowcomposeproject, PID: 24991
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1, size 1
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.MutableIntervalList.checkIndexBounds(IntervalList.kt:177)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.MutableIntervalList.get(IntervalList.kt:160)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.DefaultLazyLayoutItemsProvider.getKey(LazyLayoutItemProvider.kt:236)
```

The issue was coming from here

```
if (state.isDismissed(DismissDirection.EndToStart)) {
    onDismissed()
}
```

It seems like when you clear the `SnapshotStateList` and add another set of items, the moment the `first` item is added and the `LazyColumn` has performed an update, the `onDismissed()` is being called which also calls the `remove` function in your ViewModel immediately with the previous state and it always refers to the last item removed. In my attempt when the size was `2`, I get an Index 1 out of bounds, when the size is 3 I'm getting an Index 2 out of bounds and so on..

It may seem weird at first as everyone might expect that `rememberDismissState` will create a new state when your `ShowList` re-composes, but if you dig it a little bit, you'll see its API as a `rememberSaveable{…}` and **AFAIK**, it survives re-composition.

```
@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
fun rememberDismissState(
    initialValue: DismissValue = Default,
    confirmStateChange: (DismissValue) -> Boolean = { true }
): DismissState {
    return rememberSaveable(saver = DismissState.Saver(confirmStateChange)) {
        DismissState(initialValue, confirmStateChange)
    }
}
```

The fix on **my** **encountered** **issue**, is just to create a `remembered{..}` `DismissState`. (Note I'm not sure if there would be any other repercussions doing this aside from not surviving config changes such as screen rotation, but it solves the crash I encountered, might also solve yours)

```
val state = remember {
      DismissState(
         initialValue = DismissValue.Default
      )
}
```

Another thing I did is (not a fix but maybe an optimization) is I wrapped your dismissState function calls inside a `derivedStateOf`, because not doing so(like yours) will execute multiple re-compositions on its enclosing composable

```
val isDismissed by remember {
     derivedStateOf {
          state.isDismissed(DismissDirection.EndToStart)
     }
}

// used like this
if (isDismissed) {
    onDismissed()
}
```

And these are your modified components (all codes you posted).

```
// your Data class that I assumed
data class Product(
    val id : String,
    val name: String
)

// your Screen where I removed unnecessary codes to reproduce the issue
@Composable
fun ProductsScreen(vm: ProductsListViewModel = ProductsListViewModel()){
    ShowList(
        vm,
        { x -> vm.removeProduct(x) },
        { vm.refresh() }
    )
}

// your ViewModel where I removed unnecessary codes to reproduce the issue
class ProductsListViewModel : ViewModel() {

     var products = mutableStateListOf<Product>()

    fun removeProduct(id: String) {
        products.removeIf { x -> x.id == id }
    }

    fun refresh() {

        if(products.any()) {
            products.clear()
        }

        for (i in 0..1) {
            products.add(
                Product(
                    i.toString(),
                    "Product $i"
                )
            )
        }
    }
}

// your ShowProduct where I removed unnecessary codes to reproduce the issue
// added swipe back background and a red rectangular box to see an item
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun ShowProduct(
    onDismissed: () -> Unit
) {

    val state = remember {
        DismissState(
            initialValue = DismissValue.Default
        )
    }

    val isDismissed by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            state.isDismissed(DismissDirection.EndToStart)
        }
    }

    if (isDismissed) {
        onDismissed()
    }

    SwipeToDismiss(
        state = state,
        background = {
            Text("SomeSwipeContent")
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp, 10.dp)
            .height(75.dp),
        directions = setOf(DismissDirection.EndToStart),
        dismissThresholds = { _ -> FractionalThreshold(0.5f) }
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(50.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
    }
}


// your ShowList where I removed unnecessary codes to reproduce the issue
// and added a button to make it work
@Composable
fun ShowList(
    viewModel: ProductsListViewModel,
    onDismissed: (String) -> Unit,
    onRefreshRequested: () -> Unit
) {

    Column {

        Button(onClick = { onRefreshRequested() }) {
            Text("Refresh")
        }

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            items(items = viewModel.products, key = { product -> product.id } ) { product ->

                ShowProduct(
                    onDismissed = {
                        onDismissed(product.id)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All of them were used like this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ProductsScreen()
        }
}
```

Output: (The gif doesn't show the crashing, but if you use `rememberDismissState` instead, it will crash after clicking the button)

[image]

Note: Everything I did is to fix the `crash` issue that **I** encountered, but since I'm using your code and I just filled the missing parts, maybe it will solve yours.